# Differentiablity of functional equations

Tags: functions

Q. Let f be a differentiable function on R satisfying $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$, if $f(1)=2$, find $f(x)$.

Putting $y=0$, we get $f(0)=1$, since $f(x)$ cannot be zero.
$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $

This can be reduced to $f'(x)=f(x)f'(0)$ which upon integrating gives $f(x) = e^{f'(0)x+C}$ where C is the integration constant.

How can we proceed from here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly, $f(0) = 1$ means $C = 0$. What would $f'(0)$ have to be to satisfy $f(1) = 2$?